# Can't install sonata news bundle

Tags: composer-php, sonata-admin, php-7, symfony-3.2

I have a issue when I tried to install Sonata news Bundle. I can't find a post where someone have the same issue.

I tried to follow [sonata documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/news/3-x/doc/reference/installation.html) .

Here my composer :

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.2",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/phpcr-bundle": "~1.3@dev",
    "doctrine/phpcr-odm": "^1.4",
    "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "^5.0",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.4",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "~1.0",
    "jms/translation-bundle": "^1.3",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "~1.4",
    "liuggio/excelbundle": "^2.1",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.16",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "^3.3",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "^3.5",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-add_support_for_fos_user2",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.2.*",
    "tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles": "^2.2",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
},
```

When I tried :

> composer require sonata-project/news-bundle

I have this answer :

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for sonata-project/user-bundle dev-add_support_for_fos_user2 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[dev-add_support_for_fos_user2].
- sonata-project/news-bundle 3.1.0 requires sonata-project/user-bundle ^3.0 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[3.x-dev].
- sonata-project/news-bundle 3.1.1 requires sonata-project/user-bundle ^3.0 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[3.x-dev].
- sonata-project/news-bundle 3.1.2 requires sonata-project/user-bundle ^3.0 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[3.x-dev].
- Conclusion: don't install sonata-project/user-bundle 3.x-dev
- Installation request for sonata-project/news-bundle ^3.1 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/news-bundle[3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.2].
```

So, I tried with dev-master version (4.x-dev) of sonata user bundle :

Here my composer :

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.2",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/phpcr-bundle": "~1.3@dev",
    "doctrine/phpcr-odm": "^1.4",
    "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "^5.0",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.4",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "~1.0",
    "jms/translation-bundle": "^1.3",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "~1.4",
    "liuggio/excelbundle": "^2.1",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.16",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "^3.3",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "^3.5",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.2.9",
    "tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles": "^2.2",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
},
```

I have this answer :

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for sonata-project/user-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[dev-master].
- sonata-project/news-bundle 3.1.0 requires sonata-project/user-bundle ^3.0 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[3.x-dev].
- sonata-project/news-bundle 3.1.1 requires sonata-project/user-bundle ^3.0 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[3.x-dev].
- sonata-project/news-bundle 3.1.2 requires sonata-project/user-bundle ^3.0 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[3.x-dev].
- Conclusion: don't install sonata-project/user-bundle 3.x-dev
- Installation request for sonata-project/news-bundle ^3.1 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/news-bundle[3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.2].
```

With :

> "sonata-project/user-bundle": "3.x-dev",

Here the answer :

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for sonata-project/user-bundle 3.x-dev -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[3.x-dev].
- Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- sonata-project/user-bundle 3.x-dev requires symfony/security ^2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/security[v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9].
- don't install symfony/security v2.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.4.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.4.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.4.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.4.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.5.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.5.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.5.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.5.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.5.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.5.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.5.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.5.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.5.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.5.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.5.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.5.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.5.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.6.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.6.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.6.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.6.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.6.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.6.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.6.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.6.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.6.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.6.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.6.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.6.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.6.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.6.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.26|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.27|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.28|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.29|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.30|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.31|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.32|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.7.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.8.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.26|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.27|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.28|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.29|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.30|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.31|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.32|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.33|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.34|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.35|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.36|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.37|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.38|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.39|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.40|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.41|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.42|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- don't install symfony/security v2.3.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
- Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.2.9 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.2.9].
```

Anyone can help me ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, SonataNewsBundle lacks support of Symfony 3 or higher. 
There is this open issue: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataNewsBundle/issues/348

## I see two options

You could implement Symfony 3 support according to the issue above, or require Symfony 2.8 in your project.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0",
    ...

    "symfony/symfony": "^2.8"
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^3.2"
    ...
```

---

Just a note: please forget about "dev"-versions as long as you **don't need them** or **developing them**. You might break your project any time by just updating, which you should consider very carefully.

Comment: Thank you, I see that issue but when I see the date I hoped that it's working now :(
Thanks for your time.

Comment: SonataNewsBundle is now compatible with Symfony 3 and 4.